# Conversational Neural Network for Peak Detection and time difference of a bouncing ball

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, librosa

For fun, I tried to create a neural network that can detect the time difference (t2 - t1) of two consecutive bounces of a ball within 1.5 seconds (disregarding the third bounce). *"The idea is that if you have the time difference of the first two bounces, you can calculate the initial rebounce height, through a physics formula."*

Input for the CNN was a spectrogram image as shown below. The output is one neuron, which will output the time difference between the first bounce and the second bounce (t1 the first bounce - t2 the second bounce). Overall there are 1000 samples in this CNN.

The first two bounces can have the same time difference, but be placed somewhere else. For example, one sample might be t2-t1=0.810-0.530=0.280 and another sample might be 0.980-0.7=2.80. This is clear in example 1 and example 2.

[Exmaple 1 of Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU11D.png)

[Example 2 of Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u2wE.png)

Here is the full code (isn't much):

https://www.codepile.net/pile/Al51wXl6

Here's the network structure:

```
cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=[1025, 65, 1]))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
cnn.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=30)
```

The output was far of the accuracy I was hoping for:

```
Mean Absolute error is: ~0.3
```

So my question is, am I missunderstanding CNN's or why cant my CNN perform this task.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 1000 samples, I changed it!

Comment: What is the performance you expect? What is the typical distance between two skips?

Comment: Have you seen other example of CNNs learning a temporal/spatial distance? That sounds quite challenging.

Comment: @JonNordby The typical distance is 0.730 seconds, whilst I am getting a result of 0.9 (which is an MAE of 0.3). Additionally, I expected performance of an accuracy of 0.05. At the end of the day, this is simple peak detection, right?

Comment: @JonNordby Also, I have not been able to see another example as such. This made me wonder if CNN's are only able to find the distance of one ball bounce than the difference (which I do not believe, but surprise me if Im wrong). Also, I did not expect this problem to be so complex as you mentioned!

Comment: No, this is not simple peak detection. It is the joint detection of 2 individual peaks and estimating the distance between them. It is not a trivial thing to learn, and a plain CNN does not have a good inductive prior for the distance-estimation

Comment: The event detection itself is simple, see literature on Sound Event Detection (SED). If you make a NN that outputs the time-series of the events probability, then a 1D CNN on that should be able to estimate the distance. Learning this jointly should be possible, but could be considered as a "weakly labeled"  SED, because the individual events are not labeled

Comment: Is the data for the problem available?

Comment: Here is an example of the 1D CNN distance estimation, https://towardsdatascience.com/measuring-distance-using-convolutional-neural-network-190b7afadd8a

Comment: @JonNordby Sorry for the very late reply (my end of year exams for school). Yes I can give you a sample of my data.

Comment: @JonNordby Sorry for the very late reply (my end of year exams for school). Yes, I can give you a sample of my data.
https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20211028JTrg5ckI

I additionally changed my code a bit now, so it looks like this. It's more like the hyperlink you showed me. I used GlobalMaxPooling1d() because it gave me an error (Error: Flatten...). Whilst having the kernel size equal to the sample size (like the hyperlink), gave me the worst possible result. Chaing the kernel to a small size made for better but still inaccurate results.
Code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/zmLZ9BjV

Answer (score 0):

Most critical mistake

### Choice of loss function and output unit

You have a regression task (predicting the continious variable time-difference). But your loss function is binary_crossentropy, which is for classification. Must use something like "mean_squared_error" instead.

The output neuron non-linearity is sigmoid, which is for classification (or other things that should saturate between 0.0 and 1.0). Recomment using linear instead.

Comment: This did not alter to a better result!